# Java card game "War" gets Out of bounds exception

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm creating a java version of the card game "War" using array lists.

These are all the files, mostly based on "Java How to Program, Early Objects" by Paul Deiel
https://github.com/eldar101/EldarRep/tree/master/Game_Of_War/src

The game asks for the names of two players and splits a deck into two 26 card decks.
I've added JPanel messages to notify of the size of the deck and who wins in every turn.
It passes turns normally and reaches even hundreds of turns, but for some reason never ends and gives out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 14 out of bounds for length 14
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBounds(Preconditions.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.outOfBoundsCheckIndex(Preconditions.java:70)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.util.Preconditions.checkIndex(Preconditions.java:248)
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.checkIndex(Objects.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:425)
    at DeckOfCards.getCard(DeckOfCards.java:69)
    at Game.gamePlay(Game.java:51)
    at Game.<init>(Game.java:31)
    at main.main(main.java:5)
```

Can anyone tell me why I'm out of bounds randomly after a lot of turns? I don't know what I'm missing because the game plays normally, just doesn't reach an end and gets an exception.

This is the code for the game itself if you want to take a quick look here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;


public class Game {
    String p1, p2;
    int p1DeckSize = 0, p2DeckSize = 0;
    DeckOfCards deck, deckP1, deckP2;

    public Game() {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        deck = new DeckOfCards(); // crate a new deck
        deck.shuffle(); // Shuffle the deck
        deckP1 = new DeckOfCards();
        deckP1.clearDeck();
        deckP2 = new DeckOfCards();
        deckP2.clearDeck();
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            deckP1.addICard(i,deck.getCard(i));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            deckP2.addICard(i,deck.getCard(i+26));
        }
        deck.clearDeck();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to a game of \"War\"!");
        this.p1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter player 1's name:");
        this.p2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter player 2's name:");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, this.p1 + " is player 1 \n" + this.p2 + " is player 2");

        gamePlay();
    }

    public void gamePlay() {
        int turn = 1, i = 0;
        //int indexP1 = 0, indexP2 = 0;
        while (deckP1.deckSize() != 0 && deckP2.deckSize() != 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Turn number " + turn++);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1 + " has " + deckP1.getCard(i).toString() + "\n" + p2 + " has " + deckP2.getCard(i).toString());
            if (deckP1.getCard(i).cardValue() > deckP2.getCard(i).cardValue()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1 + " wins this turn!");
                turnWin(deckP1, deckP2, i);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1 + " : " +deckP1.deckSize() +" " + p2+ " : " +deckP2.deckSize()  );
            } else if (deckP1.getCard(i).cardValue() < deckP2.getCard(i).cardValue()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p2 + " wins this turn!");
                turnWin(deckP2, deckP1, i);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1 + " : " +deckP1.deckSize() +" " + p2+ " : " +deckP2.deckSize()  );
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The cards are equal! time for war!");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1 + " : " +deckP1.deckSize() +" " + p2+ " : " +deckP2.deckSize()  );
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1 + "'s third card is " + deckP1.getCard(i+3) + "\n" + p2  + "'s third card is " + deckP2.getCard(i+3));
                warStage(deckP1, deckP2, i);
                i++;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1 + " : " +deckP1.deckSize() +" " + p2+ " : " +deckP2.deckSize()  );

            }
            if (deckP1.deckSize() == 0)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1 + " Lost the game!" + p2 + " is the winner!");
            else if (deckP2.deckSize() == 0)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p2 + " Lost the game!" + p1 + " is the winner!");
        }
    }


    public void turnWin(DeckOfCards d1, DeckOfCards d2, int i) {
        Card temp1 = new Card(d1.getCard(i).face, d1.getCard(i).suit);
        Card temp2 = new Card(d2.getCard(i).face, d2.getCard(i).suit);
        d1.removeICard(i);
        d2.removeICard(i);
        d1.addCard(temp1);
        d1.addCard(temp2);
    }  //end method turnWin

    public void warStage(DeckOfCards d1, DeckOfCards d2, int i) {
        Card temp1 = new Card(d1.getCard(i + 3).face, d1.getCard(i + 3).suit);
        Card temp2 = new Card(d2.getCard(i + 3).face, d2.getCard(i + 3).suit);
        if (temp1.cardValue() > temp2.cardValue())
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                turnWin(d1, d2,i+1);}

        } else if (temp1.cardValue() < temp2.cardValue()) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                turnWin(d2, d1, i+1);}
        }
        else
        {
            warStage(d1,d2,i+3);
        }
    }  //end method warStage
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably in your `gameplay()` method your control goes to `warStage()` method and there if I'm not wrong, you remove "cards" from the "deck" and this `DeckOfCards` is backed by some kind of list and you simply remove an entry from the list. And then you increase the counter variable `i`.

On the other hand the size of the Deck is decreasing which is the game logic. But when the control return to the top, maybe the `DeckOfCards` has `Card` but not in the index `i` that you have specified.

Simply perform the individual deck size checks at first and then proceed with the logic. Meaning, in the `gameplay()` method, make the last two methods as the first two conditions respectively, which then makes the first condition as the third condition and make it an `else if`
So:
`if deckP1.deckSize() check`
`else if deckP2.deckSize() check`
`else if deckP1.getCard(i).cardValue() > deckP2.getCard(i).cardValue()`
and so on

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the line in question:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p1 + "'s third card is " + deckP1.getCard(i+3) + "\n" + p2  + "'s third card is " + deckP2.getCard(i+3));
```

you are getting to the point in the game where:

Player X: has all but 3 of the cards
Player Y: has 3 cards

Both players play a 5:

- Player X can lay 3 cards
- Player Y can lay 2 cards

when you attempt to get(x+3) that card doesn't exist so you get the exception you're seeing.  Without googling I have no idea how this should end, as I've never actually experienced it:

- Does the War stage happen with only 2 cards?
- Does player Y automatically lose since they can't pay the ante?

There are a few things you should probably look into doing:

1) Use Enumerations for the Face and Suit options, it might be a little safer dealing cards by doing a:

```
for all Suits
    for all Faces
        deck.add(new Card(suit,face));
```

2) Start using the array list like a stack or a queue.  Essentially you should only ever be doing

Deck.deal()

which will always take the top most card (however you look at top/bottom).  In 99% of card games (that I can think of) you only ever deal cards off the top, so being able to access the third card down, without discarding the top 3 cards makes no sense.  Now some RPG type games allow you to search decks etc, but that's a whole other set of rules.

3) Create a

```
public class Player {
    private Deck active;
    private Deck discard;
}
```

which means you can deal() from your active deck and add to your discard deck.  For example you'd have (something like):

```
p1Card = p1.deal();
p2Card = p2.deal();

if (p1Card > p2Card) 
   p2.getDiscard().addAll(p1Card, p2Card);
```

it also means that you can check p1Card against null or an DeckEmptyException and do something like:

```
p1.shuffleDiscard();
```

which would shuffle and add all cards from discard to active.  Which I think is the right way to play war, instead of just adding the won cards to the bottom of the current deck.